# With Rails Aws Gem version 2, how do you configure it to use your access keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

According to this blog post, the new version of the Aws gem switches the namespace from AWS to Aws. But what am I supposed to use instead of

```
Aws.config({
  access_key_id: "something",
  secret_access_key: "something"
})
```

It's explained here but doesn't say what the alternative is:
http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxFKSK2QJE6RPZ/Upcoming-Stable-Release-of-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby-Version-2

Instead, I get an error:

```
Uncaught exception: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Comment: Update you gems. ruby apt-get update gem1.7_alfa

Comment: The gem is up to date. That's the problem - I upgraded from version 1 to version 2 of the AWS gem, and it changed things up w/o explaining how to update.

Comment: jeff, please clarify: Which gem are you using? There are different ones for aws. Can you give us the link to the rubygems.org page? Your link goes to the 'aws-sdk' gem.

Comment: Version 2.0.28, the most recent version

Comment: what's your require: require 'aws' or require 'aws-sdk'?

Comment: It's gem "aws-sdk", "2.0.28"

Comment: so, this one: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS.config is no longer a method in v2. You now call `Aws.config.update` with a simple hash:

```
# v1
AWS.config({
  access_key_id: "something",
  secret_access_key: "something"
})

# v2
Aws.config.update({
  access_key_id: "something",
  secret_access_key: "something"
})
```

Here you have the link to the [configuration options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html#Configuration) for more info related to #v2.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this section in the doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html#Configuration
it seems that the way you configure the credentials has changed.

I can't find the .config method in the docs anymore, it is now an attribute of Aws.